# I want to $broadcast and $on a function from one controller to another

Tags: angularjs

I need help with the following code. I want to $broadcast, $on the following function from page.js(controller) to layout.js(controller). How should I do that? Thanks

```
      $scope.addToPage = function(page_id) {
        $state.go('builder', {
          page: page_id
        });
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many way to do that, but, I think this is a bad idea.

If you want just call a function everywhere (any view, controller, service), you need to declare it on `$rootScope`, because `$rootScope` is uniq for `ngApp` instance (similar to Singletone):

```js
angular
  .module('test', [])
  .run(function($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.sayHello = function() { alert('Hello'); };
  })
  .controller('AnywhereCtrl', function($scope, $rootScope) {
    $rootScope.sayHello();
  })
;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<section ng-app="test">
  <button ng-click="sayHello($event)">Hello</button>
  
 <!--<div ng-controller="AnywhereCtrl"></div>-->

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be more clear I have on my.

page.html

```
<md-button ng-click="addToPage(page_id)">
```

page.js

```
  $scope.addToPage = function(page_id) {
    $state.go('builder', {
      page: page_id
    });
  };
```

!!! I don't want to modify the layout.js just to bring the functionality from page.html/js to layout.html/js with $broadcast, $on or $emit!!!

I have the same button on the:
layout.html

```
<md-button class="md-icon-button" ng-click="addToPage(page_id)">
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: use $emit instead $broadcast and package the two function as a service]

[image: inject communicationservice to appcontroller to accept broadcast]

[image: broadcast something you want]
So , hope you can understand what i say ........... my English is so poor - - ||